# Difference between RxJava and RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

Why do we need to use RxAndroid with RxJava? What is the functional difference between them and actual use of RxAndroid and RxJava? I can't find proper answer for this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`RxAndroid` can be understood as an extension to `RxJava`, that helps you to use it on Android platform easily. See the description on [RxAndroid Github repository](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid):

> Android specific bindings for RxJava 2.
>
> This module adds the minimum classes to RxJava that make writing
>   reactive components in Android applications easy and hassle-free. More
>   specifically, it provides a Scheduler that schedules on the main
>   thread or any given Looper.

Note that when you're using `RxAndroid`, you should also use the latest `RxJava` version as a dependency:

> Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.

Answer (score 12):

RxAndroid does not replace rxjava. It is a small library of Android specific rxjava utilities. For example it makes the Android application main thread available as an rxjava scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

The major difference between RxAndroid and RxJava is Schedulers. Schedulers are specifically available in RxAndroid not in RxJava which helps in efficient threading.

https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/android-getting-started-with-reactive-programming/