# Learn Android MVVM architecture components with kotlin

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

After searching about **android architecture components** I realized that **MVVM** is better than other architectures at some points so I started to learn MVVM and I'm using **Kotlin language** but the problem is when I search for tutorials to start learning I found many components like **RxJava, RxAndroid, Dagger2, Room, Lifecycle and etc.** but they don't say why they are using them and why they choose some specific components. i will show you some examples :

> **1- Android MVVM with Dagger2, Retrofit, RxJava**
>
> **2- Android MVVM with Dagger2, Retrofit, RxAndroid**
>
> **3- Android app with MVVM dagger2 RxJava Livedata and Room**

My questions are :

**1- How should I decide to choose some of these components and work with them?**

**2- How should I know that I need to use some of them together(for example Livedata and RxJava)?**

This is really confusing for me and I don't know how to start.

Comment: Follow [the tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-app-with-arch-components/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0), and ignore RxJava until you need to execute asynchronous requests in such a way that you ***need*** the Rx operators to express what you want, instead of some MediatorLiveData ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to individually understand why to use Kotlin, MVVM, Dagger, RxJava, Retrofit.

**MVVM and Kotlin:**

https://medium.com/@zhangqichuan/android-development-with-mvvm-and-kotlin-9598c3623ce1

**RxJava and RxAndroid:**

RxAndroid is an extension to RxJava(Used for handling threads and asynchronous tasks), for more details check following links:
[Difference between RxJava and RxAndroid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651249/difference-between-rxjava-and-rxandroid)
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Retrofit-and-RxJava-RxAndroid

**Retrofit:**

https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890

**LiveData and room with kotlin:**

Room is a database layer on top of an SQLite database which used to remove boilter plate while fetching data from local sqlite database, use following links:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0

After understanding this components(Kotlin, MVVM, Dagger, RxJava and RxAndroid, Retrofit, LiveData) individually then you need to do all this things in single project, use following link:

https://github.com/egek92/Kotlin-MVVM-LiveData-Room

Comment: is it necessary to use all of them?

Comment: it is not necessary, but for better code structuring and code maintenance this things are used. so that it is important to understand each thing separately.

Answer (score 3):

As a jr. android developer, i was thinking like you but i choose a route like :

- Learn MVVM with ViewModel(AAC),LiveData,Observable pattern.
- Make your async and multi threading processes with Coroutines.
- Make your Dependency Injection with Koin.

(If you want you can see how to mix them. Koin will be added soon. https://github.com/furkanaskin/CoinStalker)

Future?

Dagger 2, maybe Rxjava etc..

Comment: Consider https://overflow.buffer.com/2016/09/26/android-rethinking-package-structure/

Answer (score 2):

If you know the Core Android basics and has done at least 1 or 2 projects then you can jump to this, https://android.jlelse.eu/why-to-choose-mvvm-over-mvp-android-architecture-33c0f2de5516

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you need is start from basics.
There are a couple of google official code labs about Android architecture.

You can start looking at this code lab and then the others.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model